# Term for "soft hate"

Tags: single-word-requests

I don't know the word for it, so I will call it *hate*, but it might seem too extreme a word for people from the US.

Example from one of the comments I got:

> Maybe you're playing the wrong sort of game, if you don't like RPG limitations. Maybe you should be playing The Sims instead (not trying to be funny here).

The person disagrees with me, but because he *softly hates* me he says I should play The Sims. If he had nothing against me, he would not say the *The Sims* part.

Comment: Maybe the person was just trying to be helpful and was not trying to offend you. But that would be a topic for a [different stack exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/17087/culture-exchange).

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here. Is it about the word 'hate'? Or an explanation of the quote? or what?

Comment: The OP mentioned [this thread](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21079/skyrim-why-there-is-limit-on-amount-of-things-you-can-carry) in his other question if anyone wanted the context. It'd be too localized if not a NARQ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The example sentence doesn't contain any suggestion the other party likes, dislikes, or *[despises](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/despise)* you.  However, it may be thought *[patronizing](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/patronizing)* or *[disrespectful](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disrespectful)*, a *[put down](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put_down)* or *[rebuke](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rebuke)*, or possibly *[mocking](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mocking)*.

Here are the related meanings of the infinitives of those terms:

- despise: To regard with contempt or scorn
- patronize: To assume a tone of unjustified superiority; to talk down to; to treat condescendingly.
- disrespect: To show a lack of respect to someone or something;  to *[diss](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/diss)*
- put down: To insult, belittle, or demean
- rebuke: To criticise harshly; to reprove
- mock: To make fun of by mimicking, to taunt

Those definitions include some relevant synonyms too.

Most likely case: the other person was *patronizing*.

Comment: Despise is too strong, isn't it? And the others in the list appear to be action verbs, whereas hate is a... well, there's another question right there. What do you call a verb that is not an action?

Comment: @HNL - Not enough context was given to say if "despise" is too strong, too weak, or what; I included that word so IAdapter can check it himself or herself in some presumably more complete context.  Regarding verbs, the linked pages include both noun and verb forms.  The question, for its part, shows a verb form: "he softly hates me".

Comment: Definitely patronising.

Comment: patronize fits the best here :) big thx!

Answer (score 10):

If *hate* is too strong, then you might consider using *dislike*.

Answer (score 3):

The person may not dislike you at all, but may have been [miffed](http://thesaurus.com/browse/miff), [peeved](http://thesaurus.com/browse/peeved), or [perturbed](http://thesaurus.com/browse/perturb).

There are plenty of other words that convey various shades of disagreeableness. Have fun browsing the thesaurus.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, I'd call the person's comment **disparaging**, from the verb *[disparage](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/disparage)*:

> 1. to speak of or treat slightingly; depreciate; belittle:
> 2. to bring reproach or discredit upon; lower the estimation of

Answer (score 1):

Maybe he finds you disagreeable?

Comment: I disagree (I hope that doesn't make me disagreeable). He doesn't know me and its just a random attack for no reason at all.

Answer (score 1):

The word 'disinclination' could be considered to mean soft hatred. One would not necessarily hate some thing but he/she would have a disinclination for it.